# Removing duplicated rows with UNION

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to fetch two queries, with the same fields, using a UNION. What I need is that duplicated rows are removed, however they are not.  Both queries contain Country, Idcustomer, Type and Cost. Below I show an example:

```
Country | Idcustomer | Type | Cost                            
Brazil       123         1      3,2
Brazil       212         1      4,1


Country | Idcustomer | Type | Cost
Brazil       123         2      5,5
Brazil       212         2      4,3
Brazil       543         2      4,2
```

After fetching, what I need is that if Idcustomer is on both queries, priorize the first one. I thought that UNION was going to resolve that, because it remove duplicated values.. but is not.

```
Country | Idcustomer | Type | Cost
Brazil       123         1      3,2
Brazil       212         1      4,1
Brazil       543         2      4,2
```

Any idea? Many thanks!

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM (
   SELECT Country, Idcustomer, type, cost 
   FROM qry_cost 
   WHERE type = 1
) AS A, 
     (
   SELECT qry_cost.Idcustomer, MIN(qry_cost.cost) AS cost_min 
   FROM qry_cost 
   WHERE type = 1 
   GROUP BY qry_cost.Idcustomer
) AS B 
WHERE A.Idcustomer = B.Idcustomer 
  AND A.cost = B.cost 
UNION 
SELECT A.* 
FROM (
   SELECT Country, Idcustomer, type, cost 
   FROM qry_cost 
   WHERE type = 2
) AS A, 
     (
   SELECT qry_cost.Idcustomer, MIN(qry_cost.cost) AS cost_min 
   FROM qry_cost 
   WHERE type = 2 
   GROUP BY qry_cost.Idcustomer
) AS B 
WHERE A.Idcustomer = B.Idcustomer 
  AND A.cost = B.cost;
```

Comment: Can you post your query as well?

Comment: Your data does not contain duplicated rows. "After fetching, what I need is that if Idcustomer is on both queries, priorize the first one. I thought that UNION was going to resolve that" ...No. That's not how `union` works. At all.

Comment: SELECT A.* FROM (SELECT Country, Idcustomer, type, cost FROM qry_cost WHERE type = 1) AS A, (SELECT qry_cost.Idcustomer, MIN(qry_cost.cost) AS cost_min FROM qry_cost WHERE type = 1 GROUP BY qry_cost.Idcustomer) AS B WHERE A.Idcustomer = B.Idcustomer AND A.cost = B.cost
 UNION
 SELECT A.* FROM (SELECT Country, Idcustomer, type, cost FROM qry_cost WHERE type = 2) AS A, (SELECT qry_cost.Idcustomer, MIN(qry_cost.cost) AS cost_min FROM qry_cost WHERE type = 2 GROUP BY qry_cost.Idcustomer) AS B WHERE A.Idcustomer = B.Idcustomer AND A.cost = B.cost;

Comment: My query get the min value within type 1 field, and the same for query 2 (type 2), and then fetch both queries.. the idea is that, type 1 precedence over type 2

Answer (score 0):

```
       create  table #Country1
(
    country nvarchar(50),
    idcustomer int, 
    type int, 
    cost decimal(19,6)

)
    create table #Country2
    (
        country nvarchar(50),
        idcustomer int, 
        type int, 
        cost decimal(19,6)

    )
    create table #Country3
    (
        country nvarchar(50),
        idcustomer int, 
        type int, 
        cost decimal(19,6)

    )


    insert into #Country1(country,idcustomer,type,cost) Values('Brazil', 123,1,3.2)

    insert into #Country2(country,idcustomer,type,cost) VALUEs  ('Brazil', 212,1,4.1)

    insert into #Country3 (country,idcustomer,type,cost)VALUES ('Brazil', 123,2,5.5)
    insert into #Country3(country,idcustomer,type,cost)VALUEs  ('Brazil', 212,2,4.3)
    insert into #Country3 (country,idcustomer,type,cost)VALUES ('Brazil', 543,2,4.2)
 -- YOUR ANSWER IS AS FOLLOWS    
     select * from #Country1 
    UNION 
    select * from #Country2
    UNION 
    select * from #Country3 where cost= 4.2 


-- DROP IT     
    DROP TABLE #Country1
    DROP TABLE #Country2
    DROP TABLE #Country3


--RESULT if you run ABOVE QUERY
```

[Reult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JqSo.jpg)

Comment: You just need three line query with a UNION and the last select query with a where clause thats it. hope it works . I have created the temp table to prove the result works as i have attached the result JPG file

Comment: thanks Udeep Dhungel, but I have as many countries as countries the world have.. Johnny Bones, could you please give an example of what WHERE clause could contains?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to determine which records to keep in an "outer" query.  By that, I mean wrap it all up in a new layer.  Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (your entire query above)
WHERE (your logic as to which records to keep)
```

Comment: The thing is I need that the query get all the rows from the first table, and join them with all no duplicated values (a row is duplicated if IdCustomer is the same) from Table 2. It would be something like LEFT JOIN Table 1 + RIGHT JOIN Table - INNER JOIN WHERE table1. IdCustomer = Table2.IdCustomer.. sorry for that stupid 'code', but I don't know how to implement it with SQL .thanks